# Additional connector to DxH in Ektron

Tags: ektron

I tried to add a new connector to DxH named AdvWrksConnector with the help of sample connector code.I have made change in 4 areas in 'CBSvcHost.exe'  as per 'Digital Experience Hub - Developer Webinar '.

After restarting the service When I opened DxH in Workarea settings I got the error

> "The system was unable to connect to the Digital Experience Hub at net.tcp://SysNo:PortNo/ContextBus.
>   Please check your DXH Connection URL or contact your IT Administrator for support."